# public Command showPopupDialog(Component c) in dialog class throwing an error

Tags: java, codenameone

Am calling a popup dialog, this throws an error.
This code previously worked, but i recently uploaded a new build and my new build now produces an error message on the 15/07/2019

public Command showPopupDialog(Component c). this is the method in the Dialog class am calling.

Getting the following error message

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codename1.ui.plaf.Border.paintBorderBackground(Border.java:1435)
[EDT] 0:0:0,19 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - null
    at com.codename1.ui.plaf.Border.paintBorderBackground(Border.java:1267)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintBackgroundImpl(Component.java:2661)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintComponentBackground(Component.java:2625)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.paintComponentBackground(Container.java:2546)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.internalPaintImpl(Component.java:2239)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternalImpl(Component.java:2228)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternal(Component.java:2203)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.paint(Container.java:1639)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.paint(Form.java:4180)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.internalPaintImpl(Component.java:2255)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.internalPaintImpl(Form.java:4190)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternalImpl(Component.java:2228)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternal(Component.java:2203)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternal(Component.java:2171)
[EDT] 0:0:0,66 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - null
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintComponent(Component.java:2468)
    at com.codename1.ui.animations.CommonTransitions.paint(CommonTransitions.java:1139)
    at com.codename1.ui.animations.CommonTransitions.initTransition(CommonTransitions.java:469)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.initTransition(Display.java:1576)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.setCurrent(Display.java:1535)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.showModal(Form.java:2303)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.showModal(Dialog.java:1138)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:582)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.showPopupDialog(Dialog.java:1287)
    at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.showPopupDialog(Dialog.java:1154)
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you're passing a parameter that's null, or you are trying to call a method on an object that is null.

So the simplest way of finding out which is null, is doing this:
`System.out.println("myObject = "+myObject);`

for every object that you're using near the nullpointer exception until you find something that's null.

Answer (score 0):

This is a regression due to the fix for [this issue](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2689). We fixed it and it will be available in the next update.

I'm guessing you have a style for `PopupDialog` in your theme. I suggest removing it as a workaround.